# Mocha/SuperTest/Request Interaction Inconsistency - request.defaults is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, request, mocha.js, supertest

This one has me stumped. I'm using [mochajs](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/) as a test suite for a NodeJS (Express 4) application. The test suite runs through a series of mocha files, all using a pretty similar set up,and when run individually they all run fine - but when run as a suite, one file suddenly fails with the error:

```
TypeError: request.defaults is not a function
    at Object.module.exports.apiName (/my/system/file/path/repo/lib/reports.js:176:30)
```

All the files used to work, even when run as a suite, but we recently switched from using to use a config.json file as the environment determinant to using `process.env.NODE_ENV` - not sure if its related but the timing lines up.

A simplified overview of the file chain would look something like:

**command line call:**

```
env NODE_ENV=local mocha test
```

...runs through file1, file2, file3, etc until:

**test/reports.js**

```
var env         = process.env.NODE_ENV,
    config      = require('../config.json');

// Libraries
var app         = require('../app'),        // Imports the application
    http        = require('http'),          // Sets up the test server on a different port
    assert      = require('assert'),        // Checks values against expected
    request     = require('supertest');     // Tests API Calls - https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest

describe.skip('Reports', function() {
    before(function(){
        // Start APP and expose on a test different port
        this.server     = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

        // Set request path to server - needs to match above
        request = request('http://localhost:3000');
    });

    describe('#NameOfAPI', function(){
        it('should return {status:"error"} if invalid report requested (Requires Mongo Running)', function(done) {
            this.slow(300);
            request
                .get('/app/reports/api/nameOfAPI?report=invalidReportName')
                .expect(200)
                .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                .end(function(err, res){
                    it(res.body)
                    assert.equal(null, err);                                                    // Ensure no errors in request
                    assert.equal('error', res.body.status);                                     // Ensure correct status returned for invalid data
                    assert.notEqual(-1, res.body.messages[1].search(/empty response/i));        // Ensure proper message returned for invalid report
                    done();

                }); // End HTTP request for invalid report

        }); // End Test for invalid report
});
```

The request (via supertest) obviously calls the route (app/reports/api)->API (nameOfAPI) module:

**lib/reports.js**

```
var env         = process.env.NODE_ENV,
    config      = require('../config.json'),
    request     = require('request');

var module.exports = {

    requestReportToCsv: function(report_name, hostname, cb){

        var req_limit   = 100;          // Set maximum concurrent requests - server returning numerous 'ECONNRESET' errors if hit too fast

        // Set HTTP request defaults outside of any loops
        // THIS IS THE LINE THAT'S FAILING - lib/reports.js:176:30
        var http_request = request.defaults({ json: true, pool: { maxSockets: req_limit } });

        if (env != 'prod') {
            http_request = http_request.defaults({headers: {'dev-cookie': 'on', 'Cookie':'dev_cookie=on'}});
        }

        http_request.post('https://website.com/api/info.php', {form: post_data}, function(err, resp, body){

             // Uncomment to see an example of the report response
             ...SO ON AND SO FORTH
```

Can't for the life of me figure out why `request.defaults({})` will work fine when the mocha test file is called individually using `env NODE_ENV=local mocha test/reports` but fail when run as part of a suite using `env NODE_ENV=local mocha test`. Any ideas?

---

Edit: Note, renaming the `var request = require('supertest')` variable `var supertest = require('supertest')` (and all subsequent references) doesn't have an effect, so I don't think it's a scope/variable/name issue.

Comment: Try running mocha with the --check-leaks flag.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Good thinking, but (un)fortunately came back clean - only errors are the assert fails:

     1) Reports #requestReportToCsv should return {status:"error"} if invalid report requested (Requires Mongo Running):
     Uncaught AssertionError: null == [Error: expected 200 "OK", got 500 "Internal Server Error"]